# React Native: Conditional props for List

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I was wondering if there is a way to set a group of properties for a list component based on a condition.

```
render() {
  return (
    <SectionList
      ref={(ref) => {this.listRef = ref}}
      style={styles.listContainer}
      sections={this.props.listData}
      fetchData={this.props.fetchData}
      keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      ItemSeparatorComponent={this.separator}
      keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
      initialNumToRender={6}
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
      // ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
      // onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
      // onEndReached={() => {
      //   this.props.fetchMoreData()}}
    />
  )
}
```

I would like `ListFooterComponent`, `onEndReachedThreshold` and `onEndReached` only to be set if `this.props.fetchMoreData` is set. Do I need to put an if-statement at the top of the render function or is it possible to create a separate prop to group those 3 and use the spread operator to put this back into the SectionList based on the condition. I am not quite sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following

```
  render() {
    optional = {}
    if (this.props.fetchMoreData) {
      optional.onEndReachedThreshold = 0.5
      optional.onEndReached = () => {
        this.props.fetchMoreData()}
      optional.ListFooterComponent = this.renderFooter
    }
    return (
      <SectionList
        ref={(ref) => {this.listRef = ref}}
        style={styles.listContainer}
        sections={this.props.listData}
        fetchData={this.props.fetchData}
        keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
        renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        ItemSeparatorComponent={this.separator}
        keyboardDismissMode='on-drag'
        initialNumToRender={6}
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
        {...optional}
      />
    )
```

I think I initially tripped over `optional.ListFooterComponent`. It just looked strange to me so I assumed it must be wrong ;)